# Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /volume1/web/comment.php on line 62

Tags: php, fopen, feof

I'm only starting to learn code with the help of youtube and other sites, and I've run tino a problem. Here's my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="c">
  <label> Name: <br><input type="text" name="name" size="36"></label><br></br>
  <label> Message: <br><textarea cols="35" rows="5" name="mes"></textarea></label><br></br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="texty" >
</form>

<?php
$post = $_POST["post"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$text = $_POST["mes"];

if ($post) {

    #WRITE DOWN COMMENTS#

    $write = fopen("c.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($write, "<u><b> $name</b></u><br>$text<br></br>");
    fclose($write);

    #DISPLAY COMMENTS#

    $read = fopen("c.txt", "r+t");
    echo "All comments:<br>";

    while (!feof($read)) {   #this line does the error#
        echo fread($read, 1024);
    }
    fclose($read);
}
else{
    #DISPLAY COMMENTS#

    $read = fopen("c.txt", "r+t");
    echo "All comments:<br>";

    while (!feof($read)) {
        echo fread($read, 1024);
    }
    fclose($read);
}
?>
```

So I have 2 files, the one where you input your comment and post it, and another .txt file where what you have typed is pasted and then echoed back on the page. 
I think something may be wrong with the permission of the files, because if i put it to "r" only, then it doesn't give me the error, but then it doesn't save what I try to post... 
Thank you for reading and replying.

Comment: understand what the error is trying to tell you..

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari I think that is the reason he is asking this question.

Comment: Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /volume1/web/comment.php on line 62 
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /volume1/web/comment.php on line 63
This are the two errors that I get, but being new to coding, they don't tell me much :/

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` will return a boolean (`FALSE`) if the file could not be opened. You should check that `$read` is not false before trying to pass it to `feof`. And then figure out why you can't read the file.

```
if ($read) {
    ...
```

Your file may be unreadable due to permissions, or if the file itself cannot be found. You are referring to `c.txt`, but is it in the same directory that PHP is in? You can find out what directory PHP is in with `getcwd`.

```
echo getcwd()
```

Also, your form handler will only enter the write branch if `$_POST['post']` has a value, but that name is not used in your form (at least not in the shown example).

Comment: I've set all file permissions to 777 so that can't be that, and idk how to check if it is false. I was only following the tutorial and after the error popped up, made sure the code was identical. you can see what i'm doing here: www.killthemall.co/test.php
Also the post will have a value once you type something in the text box i believe. Correct me if i'm wrong tho.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the file mode and where the file is located. As for the `post` value, I don't know. There is no form element named `post` in your example, and your page loads forever until I stop it, and I never get to where the browser will show me the source.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The source is already given in the main question. That's all there is :/ ALso yeah i have no idea why the page keeps on doing it forever. maybe stop it refreshing and check the source then.
I'm gonna check if $read is true now.

Comment: If you are trying to determine that the form has posted, a common idiom is to check for the submit button, e.g. `if ($_POST['submit']) {`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan, The problem was in the submit command. One was submit and the other one post, so it didn't understand what I was trying to do. 
PS: Sorry for late reply ;_;